# Intellij Formatter keeps moving method level annotation and method signature in one line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, formatting, intellij-14

I have tried several formatter settings in the IDE but I am not able to achieve following:

```
@Test
public void testMethod(){
..............
}
```

IntelliJ keeps changing above code to:

```
@Test public void testMethod(){
..............
}
```

Has anyone been able to figure this out?

Comment: I tried the same in intellij, but in my case it is not formatting like this :)

Comment: Hi Aman, can you specify which particular setting have you changed?

Comment: I have not changed anything. In my case, Intellij is working fine by default. May be you should restore defaults by going to File -> Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> JAVA and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to **Settings** and then go to
**Editor** --> **Code Style** --> **Java** ,
then switch to tab **Wrapping and Braces** ,
node **Keep when reformatting** , checkbox **Line breaks** .

Switch this checkbox **on** .

Also look at **Method annotations**

This screenshot is taken from Version 2018.1, but it should look similar in your version.

[image]

Comment: The method annotation did the trick. Actually I did not scroll down until the option Method annotation came for me to fiddle with. I thought all method level formatters were at the top (clubbed). How silly of me, but thanks Jim for the answer :)