# Intellij Scala Formatter places annotation and method definition in same

Tags: intellij-idea, methods, annotations, formatter

I am having problem similar to [Intellij Formatter keeps moving method level annotation and method signature in one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50921389/intellij-formatter-keeps-moving-method-level-annotation-and-method-signature-in).

My annotation and method definition is getting formatted in the same line. As these are two entities, should come in different lines.

Eg,

```
@Test
public void testMethod(){
..............
}
```

IntelliJ keeps changing above code to:

```
@Test public void testMethod(){
..............
}
```

I tried the same thing which is suggested in the above post, but problem with 'Keep when reformatting , checkbox Line breaks', is it keeps the line breaks everywhere. Lets say I have one long line

```
input.get(someVariableInput1, someVariableInput2, someVariableInput3, someVariableInput4,
```

And hit enter after this:

```
someVariableInput5, someVariableInput6);
```

And if we format it, it will format in following way:

```
input.get(someVariableInput1, someVariableInput2, someVariableInput3,
someVariableInput4,
someVariableInput5, someVariableInput6);
```

Which I don't want. Can someone please help here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to use scalafmt, it is better than built-in IDEA formatting

Comment: This we want to use as common format across our team, which restrict us to use built-in-IDEA formatting. Is there no way we can do this using built-in one? Wondering this is common scenario, why IDEA hasn't added this one yet.

Comment: @KrishnaKumar please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/SCL.

Comment: Sure I will do that. Thanks.